# Multithreading in Java: Wait until two buttons are pressed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently writing a small application with a Swing-Interface that contains a bunch of buttons. Now my problem is the following: After starting the application a method is called that I want to wait for two buttons to be pressed and then to proceed normally. I have two threads, one the main thread and the other one which is created just to wait until two buttons are pressed. For the buttons I added an ActionListener like usual that increases a variable by one and calls a method that wakes up the other when the variable is two.
So here's my code:

```
int counter = 0;
static Thread thread1;
static Thread thread2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                thread1 = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                        start();
                    }
                };
                thread1.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public MainFrame() {
    //other stuff and similar Listeners
    JButton button1 = new JButton();
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            count++;
            notifyIfTwo();
        }
    });
}

public void notifyIfTwo() {
    if (count == 2) {
        synchronized(thread2) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

public void start() {
    thread2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized(thread1) {
                    thread2.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread2.start();    
    //other stuff
}
```

No matter how I do it, I always get an IllegalMonitorStateException. I also tried it with a loop within thread2 that would check if the counter was two yet but I got the same result. I figure it has something to do with synchronization issues but I'm new to the whole multithreading stuff so I would appreciate it if you could get me some pointers into the right direction.
Or maybe you even know an easier way to do the whole "wait until two buttons pressed"-problem?

Thank in advance,
Regards

Comment: This doesn't even compile! What is `thread`? Are you lying to us?

Comment: No just edited it. Made a mistake simplifying it. It is for a little game I'm trying to write. I just wanted to leave out as much unnecessary stuff as possible. Sorry :)

Comment: @HolgerPappenstiel Can you correct any compile errors. For instance `Thread.wait()` and `notifyAll()`.  Both of those I would expect to throw IllegalMonitorStateExceptions.  I like the idea that you are trying to create a small subset of your code, but that subset should at least be correct.  Also `start()` in your `run` method will throw a RuntimeException for starting the same thread twice

Comment: fix the compile errors in this copy of your code.

Comment: Well that's embarrasing. I think i fixed it now. Maybe next time I shouldn't do this "on the fly" lol Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). It allows to wait given number of `countDown()` invocations.

`Thread.wait();` in your code doesn't make sense, it could not compile. The `wait` method could be applied on a object which you are synchronizing.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is causing your exceptions is that thread1 is accessing GUI components off the UI thread.  One way to approach this is to get rid of thread1.  Have your onClick (or actionPerformed) handlers increment the variable.  Have thread2 just loop and monitor the variables value after waiting (say 500mS).

So you can keep the invoke later, with the runnable, but do the work in the outer run method like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}

public void start() {
thread2 = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
                while (keepGoing)
                {
                    thread2.sleep(500);
                    if (variableIncremented)
                    {
                        // doSomething();
                        // reset variable, or set keepGoing = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
    thread2.start();    
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: Just tried it. I don't get the IllegalMonitorStateException anymore but it doesn't wait for me to push the buttons but immediately skips ahead to the following method which then of course gives me a NPE.

Comment: OK, slow down.  If the only place the variable can get incremented is your button handlers and the other method waits for the variable to be incremented something weird is happening.  debug it in eclipse or put print statements everywhere as one of our assumptions is false.

Comment: Maybe you want to call the "following method" where I have "doSomething()".

Comment: That's how I had it in the beginning with a loop that breaks when the counter is two. But that didn't work so I changed it. What I meant with "following method" is the other stuff after thread2 is started. Perhaps with the implementation I have currently with wait() the //other stuff methods are already executed while thread2 is waiting? Because that would explain some things.

Comment: I think that the problem in the beginning was with thread1 and that this should work now.

Answer (score 1):

The point is this:

```
    synchronized(thread2) {
        notifyAll();
    }
```

You are notifying all threads that wait on `this`, yet you do not have the monitor for `this`.
For all wait/notify/notifyAll, the code must be:

```
 synchronized (foo) {
    foo.wait();    // or foo.notify()
 }
```

Likewise, later you have:

```
  synchronized(thread1) {
     thread2.wait();
  }
```

You can't synchronize on obj1 and wait on obj2, unless obj1 == obj2.

Comment: Ok, thanks I fixed that. Still having the problem I described in the comment to the other answer though

Comment: I changed it like you showed so I currently have synchronized(thread1) { thread1.notifyAll(); } and synchronized(thread2) { thread2.wait(); }

Comment: That helps with the MonitorStateException, but now you wait and notify on different objects? Keep in mind also that you must wait in a loop like `while (count < 2) synhronized ....` because of possible spurious wakeups.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out now. The remaining problem was that I didn't separate the GUI-thread and the other thread contaiing the logic strictly enough (outside of the code I posted).
Thanks to everyone that helped me with figuring out the IllegalMonitorStateException.
I now used CountDownLatch like someone suggested and it works like a charm.